# MonoDevelop-like autocompletion in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ide, autocomplete, intellisense, monodevelop

I really like the way MonoDevelop's automcomplete / intellisense feature works.

Specifically I like the way it suggests words according to letters I type: for example, for word like `SomeMethodName` I only need to type `S` and `M` and maybe `N` and suggestion looks like this:

> **S** ome **M** ethod **N** ame

My question is: is there any extension / add-in for Visual Studio (2010) that would provide this kind of feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) does exactly this, among many other things.

See [Code Completion](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#Code_Completion) on their site.

Comment: +1 Thank you, I didn't mention it before, I'm rather looking for a free extension and possibly not doing anything else (so that it doesn't slow down VS too much).